# How to get thumbnail and Original image from UIImagePickerViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

After captured photo from camera, I was doing image compression For (400kb and 1 Mb), it look almost 3 seconds in iPhone 6 and less than a second in iPhone 6s.
Is there any way to get thumbnail and original image without doing manual compression?

> Code used for image compression

### Extension for UIImage

```swift
extension UIImage {
    // MARK: - UIImage+Resize
    func compressTo(_ expectedSizeInMb:Int) -> Data? {
        let sizeInBytes = expectedSizeInMb * 1024 * 1024
        var needCompress:Bool = true
        var imgData:Data?
        var compressingValue:CGFloat = 1.0
        while (needCompress && compressingValue > 0.0) {
            if let data:Data = jpegData(compressionQuality: compressingValue) {
                if data.count < sizeInBytes {
                    needCompress = false
                    imgData = data
                } else {
                    compressingValue -= 0.1
                }
            }
        }

        if let data = imgData {
            if (data.count < sizeInBytes) {
                return data
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

#### usage:

```swift
if let imageData = image.compressTo(1) {
print(imageData)
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried any 3rd party library for achieving this?

Comment: @SathyaSrinivas6 Nope. Do I need to use third party libraries to achieve

Comment: func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
           if let selectedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage  {
       //presentAlert(withTitle: "", message: "Invalid resource")
               profilePic.setImage(selectedImage, for: .normal)
               imageData = selectedImage.convertImageToBase64String()
           }
                     picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           }

Comment: @Swiftyspot Try using this 3rd party library **SDWebImage**. it is available in github. It stores the images in the cache once downloaded or provides some default image to display.

Answer (score 1):

**For images saved in Photos Library :**

Try :

```
  let phAsset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as! PHAsset
  let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
  options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
  options.isSynchronous = false

                         // you can change your target size to CGSize(width: Int , height:  Int) any number you want.
  PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: phAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .default, options: options, resultHandler: { image , _ in

        let thumbnail = image
        // use your thumbnail
    })
```

**For Captured images from Camera, you can get image pixels without recalculating data count :**

```
 let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

        // pixels are the same on each device’s camera
    let widthPixels = image.size.width * image.scale
    let heightPixels = image.size.height * image.scale
    let sizeInBytes = 1024 * 1024

    var thumbnail : UIImage! = nil

    if Int(widthPixels * heightPixels) > sizeInBytes {
                 // assign custom width and height you need
         let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100, height: 100)
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 1)
         let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
         context?.interpolationQuality = .low
         image.draw(in: rect)
         let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
         thumbnail = resizedImage

    } else {

        thumbnail = image

    }
```

Comment: Getting nil  here `guard let phAsset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset else {return}`

Comment: Did you save your captured Image to Photos Library?

Comment: No, I haven't @K4747Z